# Lose ASP.NET Session for one request and then regains it on next

Tags: asp.net, session, cookies

I am seeing a very strange problem on one of my production boxes. We have an application hosted in IIS 6 on a single machine with an apache web server in front of it.  My application is using ASP.NET Membership for authentication and relies on session state.  I am seeing a problem right now where some server requests will hit a null exception when trying to access any session variables, but if the request is retried, the page hits no exceptions and behaves properly.

I believe this has something to do with the Session ID cookie either getting corrupted or lost on the request, but I have no idea what could cause that.  The reason I believe this is because it seems like ASP.NET is not seeing the cookie and creating a new session, which would explain why the variables are null.  When it gets the exception, it cannot write the new SessionID cookie back to the client, so the client still maintains the original SessionID.  Then when the next request is sent, the original SessionID cookie is used, which now ASP.NET finds and is able to retrieve the session state.  This is pure speculation, but seems to fit the symptoms.

Also this site is using no other cookies other then the ones required by ASP.NET Membership and ASP.NET Session, so I am well under the cookie limit for IE.  The site has been functioning properly for about 8 months and this issue just popped up recently.  I have tried IIS resets and actually rebooting the machine, but nothing has seemed to help the problem.

Updates:

Here are some clarifications that were asked for.

1.)Our Apache server is the only thing exposed to the internet.  All requests occur over HTTPS to this box.  The Apache box then forwards all request past over HTTP to our application server.  This is being done for security reasons.  We have looked to see if Apache might have been the issue, but there seems to be no error in the Apache logs.

2.)The null exception is occurring when trying to access an object stored in session that the application expects to be there as opposed to the exception happening with the actual session object itself.

Comment: Can you clarify your setup? I have no idea what you mean by IIS 6 "with an apache web server in front of it." What is actually handling HTTP requests from the web? Also, is the null exception on the actual Session object, or just that the objects you expect to be in the Session are not there? One of those things... well, should never happen! Even if the session id cookie got lost, ASP.NET should create a new valid Session object.

Comment: You're forwarding requests from an Apache box to an IIS box for "security" reasons?  I don't think your network guys know what they are doing.

Comment: We have a DMZ zone that is basically another layer in front of our applications so that they are not exposed to the net.  It also allows for URL rewriting which you really can't do with a .NET tech stack unless you upgrade to IIS7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found the root of the issue.  It looks like the IIS meta-base got corrupted on our app server.  The best way to fix this issue is to do a clean install of IIS, but because of business constraints, this is not an option for us.  So another solution is to actually just create a new App Pool for the application to run under.  According to some people with more IIS expertise than myself, this will fix the problem in the short term, but it is very likely that the same thing will happen to this App Pool.  So we are required to create new App Pools if this starts occurring again.